# How to connect from one bridge to another?

Tags: networking, mikrotik

I have Mikrotik router and two bridges.

private-bridge: eth1, eth2 (10.20.0.0/24)

public-bridge: eth3, eth4, eth5 (192.168.88.0/24)

I have on printer on eth1 and I want be able to connect from eth4.

Is it possible some how to do it over Firewall NAT?

Thank you

Comment: You are using private addressing on both bridges, so you really do not want to use NAT. Simple routing will route between the networks. If you have a firewall enabled, you may just need to set up a firewall rule to allow the traffic you want between the bridges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routing between local networks is automatic with Mikrotik OS.

If your devices (printer and computer) both have the mikrotik router as default gateway, they should be able to ping themselves and communicate.

Il default route is not possible, you can add route on each device to the other network, i.e.

- On computer: route add 10.20.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 [Mikrotik IP in 192.168.88 network]
- On printer: it depends on the brand but usually you can add a route in network page.

Comment: Can I setup this on Mikrotik? I cannot ping computer from 192.168 to 10.20.

Comment: There is nothing much more to setup, all you need is a route from device in 192.168 network to 10.20 and vice versa, as explained above. Also, maybe check as Ron Maupin told you, if there is no firewall rule blocking traffic between the two networks.